# How should the proc tag be split up?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [proc](/questions/tagged/proc) tag refers to at least three concepts:

1. In Ruby (and other languages including TCL?), it refers to a piece of code converted into an object.
2. Pro*C is an embedded SQL programming language.
3. In Linux (any other unices?), it refers to `/proc` or something related.

I'm not sure how to split the tags up.

For the first one, as it doesn't seem to be Ruby only, I don't think ruby-proc would work, apart from as a synonym. Would proc-object work? Are procs objects in the other programming languages?

For the second one, I guess it could be called proc-language, if that's the accepted terminology.

Hammar has suggested in comments the third one be called procfs or proc-filesystem.

**Update:** For Ruby and friends, it's been changed to [proc-object](/questions/tagged/proc-object). For the Linux term, it should be changed to [procfs](/questions/tagged/procfs) as it's an existing tag.

Comment: How about [`procfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) or maybe `proc-filesystem`?

Comment: Maybe the second could be `proc-sql`?

Comment: Is Pro*C specific to oracle? In which case it could be oracle-proc