# Notify depopulation of favorite tags

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

I've been depopulating the [proc](/questions/tagged/proc) tag because it's [ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107791/how-should-the-proc-tag-be-split-up), but there's 2 people who are following the tag. Can users tell if their tag is being depopulated, apart from the derth of new questions using that tag?

Two possibilities I can think of:

1. List in the "Active" tab for a given tag questions that have had the tag removed.
2. Highlighting in the "Favorite tags" area the favorite tag with a color to indicate that it's been depopulated until the user "acknowledges" the fact.